# Using Weblogic 12c, giving warning Warning Log Management BEA-170011 The LogBroadcaster on this server failed to

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I am using weblogic 12c server to deploy my web applications. These were running fine but now it has started showing the following warning : -

```
<Warning> <Log Management> <BEA-170011> 
<The LogBroadcaster on this server failed to broadcast log messages to the Administration Server. 
The Administration Server may not be running. Message broadcasts to the Administration Server will be disabled.>
```

I am not able to see even home page of my web application. Please help me, I am a java programmer having very limited knowledge in weblogic admin. The full stack trace from console is given below: -

```
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1/common/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1211\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_oepe101\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_12.1.1.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1211\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_oepe101\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\jre\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;H:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;G:\Java Latest sw\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin\java -client -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1/jre/lib/endorsed;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1/endorsed  -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole... -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1211\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_oepe101\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
<24 Oct, 2013 2:27:58 AM IST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:27:58 AM IST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:27:58 AM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM Version 20.4-b02 from Sun Microsystems Inc..> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:27:59 AM IST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13340309 Thu Feb 16 18:30:21 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13019800 Mon Jan 16 16:53:54 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13391585 Thu Feb 02 10:18:36 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13516712 Mon Jan 30 15:09:33 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13641115 Tue Jan 31 11:19:13 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13603813 Wed Feb 15 19:34:13 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13424251 Mon Jan 30 14:32:34 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 13361720 Mon Jan 30 15:24:05 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13421471 Wed Feb 01 11:24:18 IST 2012
WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for BUG13657792 Thu Feb 23 12:57:33 IST 2012
WebLogic Server 12.1.1.0  Wed Dec 7 08:40:57 PST 2011 1445491 > 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:03 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:03 AM IST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:03 AM IST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms, such as Windows.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:03 AM IST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log00188. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:03 AM IST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:10 AM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:21 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:21 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:28 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <The hostname "sandeep-PC", maps to multiple IP addresses: 192.168.1.3, fe80:0:0:0:14c7:40c0:a13:48cf%12, fe80:0:0:0:30:7de:3f57:fefc%22, 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:30:7de:3f57:fefc.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:30:7de:3f57:fefc:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:103:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[6]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:420:97be:9c27:f48d:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:1d35:404c:e9c6:519d:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[7]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[8]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on 192.168.1.3:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:30:7de:3f57:fefc:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[5]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:14c7:40c0:a13:48cf:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started the WebLogic Server Administration Server "AdminServer" for domain "base_domain" running in development mode.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.> 
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:31 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <The server started in RUNNING mode.> 
24 Oct, 2013 2:28:32 AM weblogic.wsee.persistence.StoreCleaner <init>
INFO: StoreCLeaner created for <StoreConnection> : storeName = WseeJaxwsFileStore connectionName = weblogic.wsee.reliability2.store.SourceSequenceStore with interval=600000 msecs, maxObjectLifetime=86400000 msecs maxIdleTimeMillis=-1 msecs with disabled = false
24 Oct, 2013 2:28:32 AM weblogic.wsee.persistence.StoreCleaner startCleanup
INFO: StoreCLeaner starting for <StoreConnection> : storeName = WseeJaxwsFileStore connectionName = weblogic.wsee.reliability2.store.SourceSequenceStore with interval=600000 msecs, maxObjectLifetime=86400000 msecs maxIdleTimeMillis=-1 msecs with disabled = false
24 Oct, 2013 2:28:32 AM weblogic.wsee.persistence.StoreCleaner <init>
INFO: StoreCLeaner created for <StoreConnection> : storeName = WseeJaxwsFileStore connectionName = weblogic.wsee.reliability2.store.DestinationSequenceStore with interval=600000 msecs, maxObjectLifetime=86400000 msecs maxIdleTimeMillis=-1 msecs with disabled = false
24 Oct, 2013 2:28:32 AM weblogic.wsee.persistence.StoreCleaner startCleanup
INFO: StoreCLeaner starting for <StoreConnection> : storeName = WseeJaxwsFileStore connectionName = weblogic.wsee.reliability2.store.DestinationSequenceStore with interval=600000 msecs, maxObjectLifetime=86400000 msecs maxIdleTimeMillis=-1 msecs with disabled = false
<24 Oct, 2013 2:28:33 AM IST> <Warning> <Log Management> <BEA-170011> <The LogBroadcaster on this server failed to broadcast log messages to the Administration Server. The Administration Server may not be running. Message broadcasts to the Administration Server will be disabled.>
```

Comment: What URL are you using trying to hit your app?

Comment: http://localhost:7001/myapp/user-login

Comment: Also, when i hit the above url in console i can see the following lines :

Comment: <24 Oct, 2013 3:40:45 AM IST> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:54,420 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.>

Answer (score 0):

Please review the following documentation from Oracle:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/03-DeployApps/deployapps.htm

Answer (score 0):

I checked several similar situations, and the BEA-170011 appears when the AdminServer isn't responding, thus it's just a consequence.

After this warning comes up, the JVM could crash, it could get stuck or an OOM could be produced, between other incidents.

Note that in this particular case, the server you are trying to start is the admin server.

Don't worry about BEA-170011, the right question is, Why isn't the AdminServer responding?

There you may have several options.

- if the JVM ended up in a crash, check the hs_err_pid log file for tips (in Linux based environments).
- if an OOM was produced with a heap dump file. Analyze the heap dump file with Eclipse MAT.
- if an OOM was produced without a heap dump file, configure the JVM to produce one under OOM condition, using these JVM options in the DOMAIN/setDomainEnv.sh: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=HeapDumpOOMR_[SERVER_NAME].hprof
- if after that warning, the server just gets freeze, take a thread dump (C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin\jstack [pid]) to know which thread got stuck. That will give you more tips.
- corruption at the embeddedLDAP.
- SSL misconfiguration (not for your particular case)
  You can try increasing the heap (for this example 512m was used --> -Xmx512m).

As you can see, the BEA-170011 is just the beginning of an adventure.

Answer (score -1):

This is very common issue with weblogic server. All you have to do is to "Configure the Listen Address for every server"

Login to console and go to 
environment>server>admin/managed server
Under configuration>general Tab, 
you will find "Listen Address".

Provide the IP or host anme in this field for admin as well as every managed server.

and its done